# Does $\mathsf{NSPACE}( f (n)) = \mathsf{coNSPACE}( f (n))$ hold for $ f(n) < \log (n) $?

Tags: complexity-theory, space-complexity

It's known that for $f(n) \geq \log n$,  $\mathsf{NSPACE}(f(n)) = \mathsf{coNSPACE}(f(n))$.

What if $f(n)<\log n$? Are they also equal?

Comment: AFAIR, the result only holds for *space constructable* bounds, not for arbitrary $f(n)\geq\log n$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Immerman–Szelepcsényi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immerman%E2%80%93Szelepcs%C3%A9nyi_theorem) theorem  works under logarithmic reductions. Sublogarithmic space classes have different reductions. The TMs working within **sublogarithmic space cannot even record the the length of the input**. It has been shown that the space hierarchy for any sublogarithmic bound in **Ω(log log n)-- o(log n)** is inﬁnite. You can find it in following references:

V. Geffert. **Sublogarithmic σ2-space is not closed under complement and other separation
results**. Theoretical Informatics and Applications, 27:349–366, 1993.

M. Liśkiewicz and R. Reischuk. **Separating the lower levels of the sublogarithmic space
hierarchy**. In Proceedings of the Symposium on Theoretical Aspects of Computer Science,
pages 6–27, 1993.

B. von Braunmuhl "**Alternation for two-way machines with sublogarithmic space**". In Proceedings of the Symposium on Theoretical Aspects of Computer Science, pages 5–15, 1993.

The paper **The complexity world below logarithmic space** by M. Liśkiewicz and R. Reischuk contains an excellent wrap up of the sublogarithmic space.